# Redis pipelining in Quarkus

Tags: java, redis, pipeline, quarkus

I'm facing an issue with the Redis connection pool, reaching the max wait queue size, at moments with more reads. There are some reads in a loop that would be good to batch in one request to Redis. But I cannot find a way to use Redis pipelines with Quarkus Redis Client. Is there a way to do it?

Here is my Redis service:

```
public class CacheService {

    private final HashCommands<String, String, CachedData> redisHash;

    protected CacheService(RedisDataSource redis) {
        this.redisHash = redis.hash(CachedData.class);
    }

    protected CachedData get(String name) {
        return redisHash.hget("data", name);
    }
}
```

And here are the multiple reads in a loop that can be done with pipelines:

```
names.stream().map(cacheService::get).toList();
```

How I can use Redis pipelines with Quarkus?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot *batch* yet with the data source API. However, the underlying client do support batch:

```
@Inject Redis redis;

// ...
redis.batch(List.of(req1, req2, req3));
```

Comment: Where I can import this Redis client from?

Comment: See https://quarkus.io/guides/redis-reference#apis and https://quarkus.io/guides/redis-reference#vert-x-redis-client. Everything is provided by the quarkus-redis extension.